# How to send parameter in page url without response and redirect or change value in url?

Tags: asp.net, url, parameters

Ineed to put parameter in web-page url. But it must be not like this:

```
Response.Redirect("Pagename?par1=1212")
```

I think it would be like this:

```
Page.Url.Parameters.Add("parameterName", parameterValue);
```

But I don't know how it must be in practice.

I need it because:
I have parameters in Session which affect on query condition. In my site users open two or more web pages with different data. And Session parameters from one page affect to another page.

Comment: from what I understand, you want your http response to set the client address bar value, without doing a redirect. Im afraid you can't do that...

Answer (score -1):

You can use it easily by:

```
string ParameterValue = "Parameter value";
Response.Redirect("Pagename?par1=" + ParameterValue );
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand me. I need to put parameters without Response.Redirect